# Need help for Parallax Eddie Robot!! Got stuck at step 6, ROSMAKE does not work

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am following the tutorial for Parallax Eddie Robot from Ros all the way up to step 6 and got stuck there. When I first trying to "rosmake" it, it told me this:

**[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['eddiebotdsdadsadsa']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.**

After I searched around and changed the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, I got different errors each time.

**christopher@christopher-Lenovo-G770:~$ export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/christopher/fuerte_workspace/sandbox:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/home/christopher/eddiebot-master
christopher@christopher-Lenovo-G770:~$ rosmake eddiebot
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...

[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['eddiebot']

[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/christopher/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130517-141651
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['eddiebot'] to:
['eddiebot_description', 'eddiebot_driver', 'eddiebot_node', 'eddiebot_bringup']
cannot find required resource: joystick_drivers
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/christopher/fuerte_workspace/sandbox
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [4]=/home/christopher/eddiebot-master**

**christopher@christopher-Lenovo-G770:~$ rosmake eddiebot
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...

[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['eddiebot']

[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/christopher/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130517-140545
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['eddiebot'] to:
['eddiebot_description', 'eddiebot_driver', 'eddiebot_node', 'eddiebot_bringup']
cannot find required resource: common_msgs
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/christopher/eddiebot**

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62993/need-help-for-parallax-eddie-robot!!-got-stuck-at-step-6,-rosmake-does-not-work/) by [ChristopherX](https://answers.ros.org/users/4922/christopherx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-07-03**:
Please link to the tutorial you are following.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just had the same problem and the above answers did not work for me.  However, I followed the directions in the following link and I'm now a little further along.  It looks like you basically have to install each package needed.

[link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/35945/rosdep-install-joy/)

---

Originally posted by [Dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19555/dan/) with karma: 16 on 2014-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0